# Searchbox on Sheet1 for finding a specific row on a table placed in Sheet2

Tags: search, row, spreadsheet, highlight, matching

I have in Openoffice Calc  a table with **4 columns**(ID-number-, text, date_out and date_in) with 400 rows on **sheet2**.

For an easy operating, I thought to have on **sheet1** a **searching cell** where to input the unique I**D**(**number**) and as a function's result to ***jump on sheet2 to the ID's row***.

I wonder if it is possible.

I wish to do that if possible in OpenOffice Calc or WPS Spreadsheet